# Javascript truncate function not working with special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

I have a function written in jQUery/ javascript that goes through all H3 tags in my document and truncates then to 49 characters then adds "..." at the end. The function works perfectly for the english version of the website but for the french version it does work. I get somewhat of an error where the character "é" from the first h3 in the page is rendered as a little black box with a question mark and from there the function still truncates the rest of the h3's but does not appear to add in the "..." at the end. So the two issues here would be the special character rendering as the black question mark and the "..." not being added in. Here is my code:

```
jQuery(".blog-container h3").each(function(){
var headertext = jQuery(this).text();
if (headertext.length > 49)  {
jQuery(this).text(headertext.substring(0,49) + "...");
}
});
```

After doing a bit of research I though it might be an escape issue so I tried wrapping the headertext variable in an escape() but still had the same issue in French.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe it's something relate with encoding? Are you using UTF-8?